# Selector in change event

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
var deliveryform = ('form[id$="shipping_method"]');

$('body').on('change', (deliveryform "input[type=radio]"), {}, function(event) {
  console.log('you changed the radio');
});
```

But my selector isn't working - do I need to change something here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate the string selector. Although you are provided the third argument as `{}` which is not necessary at all since you don't want to pass any data at all.

```
var deliveryform = 'form[id$="shipping_method"]';

$('body').on('change', deliveryform + " input[type=radio]", function(event) {
  //                   -----------^^^^^^^---------------^^^^^^-----
  console.log('you changed the radio');
});
```

---

If all those are loaded initially then there is no need of [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) at all just bind the handler directly to the element.

```
$('form[id$="shipping_method"] input[type=radio]').change(function(event) {
  console.log('you changed the radio');
});
```

---

If the form inputs are added dynamically then replace `body` with the form selector.

```
$('form[id$="shipping_method"]').on('change', "input[type=radio]", function(event) {
  console.log('you changed the radio');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax isn't quite right. Use `deliveryform` as the primary selector. Try this:

```
var $deliveryform = $('form[id$="shipping_method"]');    
$deliveryform.on('change', "input[type=radio]", function(event) {
    console.log('you changed the radio');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use like this:

```
var deliveryform = $('form[id$="shipping_method"]'); // was missing dollor sign
deliveryform.on('change', "input[type=radio]", {}, function(event) {
  console.log('you changed the radio');
});
```

Alternative answer to your question:

```
var deliveryform = 'form[id$="shipping_method"]'; // removed ()

$('body').on('change', deliveryform + " input[type=radio]", {}, function(event) {
//.                 ^^------------------^^
  console.log('you changed the radio');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You miss the `$` on your `form` selector.
2. You already have an `form` object, so why bind the `change` event on the `body`? Just use the form!

---

```
var deliveryform = $('form[id$="shipping_method"]');

deliveryform.on('change', "input[type=radio]", function() {
    console.log('you changed the radio');
});
```